# Pruebas unitarias a BehaviorSubject<string> en ionic con angular

Tags: angular, ionic, karma-jasmine

estoy haciendo un BehaviorSubject que obtiene la version de codigo de la app, tiene una funcion `getValue()` que devuelve el codigo (string).

```
private versionCode: BehaviorSubject<string>;

        getValue(): Observable<string> { //test aqui
           return this.versionCode.asObservable(); //test here
        }

      initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version => {
            this.versionCode.next(version); //test aqui
          });
          SplashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
```

Ya he intentado pero fala algo, me pueden hacer el favor de orientar,
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

```
  it('should observable',  async ()  => {
       component.getValue().subscribe(data =>
        expect(data).toString());
  });
```